# How to display datatable index by Id?

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I have parttime driver with action button direct go to parttime form with that driver Id once I click it. The issue is when I add 2 or more parttime driver. the datatable shows all parttime driver.

here's how the flow works. Add driver->choose parttime->button go to parttime form->add parttime.

Ex: I've added parttime driver 1, and I want to add another parttime driver the datatable index show driver 1. how to display only that driver by Id on datatable index?

here's my datatable code so far:

```
public function datatableBuilder(Request $request, $obj = null) {
    return PartTimeAvailability::with('driver', 'shift')->select('part_time_availabilities.*');  
}
```

[image: Driver Form]

[image: Parttime Form]

Comment: can you give example pls, what output you are getting and what you want

Comment: what kind of info u need ?

Comment: what data are you getting for the above query

Comment: thanks for screenshots ,and what exactly you want  as I am not getting your problem

Comment: I want once i click set parttime on driver Bery, it's only show bery parttime form. show by driver id. updated thread. thanks

Comment: ohk, got what you want, now pls show me the table structure, this is the last time I am asking something :P

Comment: u mean database/model relation ? it's okay, just ask anything you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129200/discussion-between-andrew-vanusi-and-kapil-dev).